# ODBC Simba Athena installation

Tags: powerbi, connection, odbc, amazon-athena, simba

I have already installed ODBC in my computer and when I want to connected with Power BI it gives me this error message:

> ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [Simba][DriverIAMSupport] (8600) Connection Error: ValidationError: 1 validation error detected: Value 'abc' at 'roleArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 20 (HTTP response code: 400)

I have already clear all permissions in Power BI and make sure the region, that was my previous step.

I try to clear the permissions from the global permissions in Power BI and then when the sig in option appears to log in into an account I place the first option and it does not let me continue because it says it could validate my credentials. So I do not know if there is an error on the ODBC that I need to check and revise.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the actual value you are providing for `roleArn`? It should look like `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-odbc-role`. You can obtain the IAM Role ARN from the IAM management console.